# Trying to change the size of a font in my iPhone game and getting this error

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, cocos2d-iphone, size

I have the following where I am trying to get this label in large fonts. I am doing the following:

```
myScoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", totalPointsPlayer];
myScoreLabel.fontName = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:30];
```

I get this error: **`Incompatible pointer types assigning NSString *'from UIFont *'`**

Is their a way to change another way to change the size of the font? Thanks I am somewhat new to Objective C coding and I am trying to learn while building a tiny game. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UILabel does not provide a `string` or a `fontName` property.  Try ...

```
myScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", totalPointsPlayer];
myScoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:30];
```

**EDIT** - Understand now that this is a cocos2d control.  I have limited experience with it, but a glance at the docs for CCTLabelTTF indicates that `fontName` is an `NSString`, not a `UIFont`.

```
myScoreLabel.string = // as you had it (using the string property, not text)
myScoreLabel.fontName = @"Arial";
myScoreLabel.fontSize = 30.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, no luck. I am getting the following errors: property 'text' not found on objects of type CCTLabelTTF *' and property 'font' not found on objects of type CCTLabelTTF *'

Comment: Oh...super important that this isn't a UILabel, but part of cocos2d.  Definitely update your question and tags.  I edited with my best understanding of cocos2d.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. Sorry I did not mention it clearly.